# How to set position of a dynamic body in andengine?

Tags: andengine, sprite

I'm developing a game using Box2D. I have to move ball according to accelerometer. I have created a body n connected ballsprite to it. I'm moving body using setLinearVelocity(). once the ball reaches the boundaries of screen,i want to stop the movement of ball at the edge of the screen. How do i do this?

```
public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData arg0) {
    ballBody.setLinearVelocity(arg0.getX(), 0);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the body velocity to zero when reach the boundaries.Place the condition in update handler and then place below statement

```
 body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
```

(or) you can make the the body  type to static

```
  body.setType(BodyType.Static);
```